# shell date "-n hours" differs with "n hours ago" in some situation

Tags: shell, date

in shell, when I print this

```
date -d "2016-11-23 13:05 -1 hours "  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"
```

I get `2016-11-23 23:00:00.`Strange!

when I print this

```
date -d "2016-11-23 13:05 1 hours ago"  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"
```

I get `2016-11-23 12:00:00`.

Why they are different? What I think is that they are both `2016-11-23 12:00:00`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the negative number is treated as an offset to your timezone, not to the `13:05`. In my timezone, MET (one hour east of GMT), this is what I get:

```
$ date -d "2016-11-23 13:05 -1 hours "  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"
2016-11-23 16:00:00
$ TZ=GMT date -d "2016-11-23 13:05 -1 hours "  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"
2016-11-23 15:00:00
$ TZ=GMT-1 date -d "2016-11-23 13:05 -1 hours "  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"
2016-11-23 16:00:00
$ TZ=GMT-1 date -d "2016-11-23 13:05 -2 hours "  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"
2016-11-23 17:00:00
```

The timezone offset is usually specified as a four digit number, as in

```
Sun, 29  Feb 2004  16:21:42 -0800
```

but apparently date(1) is happy with a -1 as well.

From the man page:

> DATE STRING
>
> The --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29  Feb
>   2004  16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".  A date string may
>   contain items indicating calendar date, time of day, time  zone,  day  of  week,  relative
>   time,  relative  date,  and  numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning of the day.
>   The date string format is more complex  than  is  easily  documented  here  but  is  fully
>   described in the info documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I want.